# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController actually executing

Tags: iphone, abpeoplepickerview

i have the contact list showing up perfectly in the simulator. it takes the phone number and places it in the text box. so i decided to try it on my iphone and it actually executes the thing i tap on. it calls the number instead of putting the number ito the textbox. heres the code:

```
- (IBAction) adressBook: (id) sender {
 // creating the picker
 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
 // place the delegate of the picker to the controll
 picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

 // showing the picker
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 // releasing
 [picker release];
}


- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    // assigning control back to the main controller
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

 /* 
 ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
 num.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);


    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 */
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
 NSLog(@"inbool");
 ABMultiValueRef phonePro = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
 int idx = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(phonePro, identifier);
 num.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonePro, idx);


 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 /*
 ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
 num.text = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, identifier);
 */


 return YES;
}
```

and sorry if not formatted correctly, new to stackoverflow.

Comment: "sorry if not formatted correctly, new to stackoverflow"? The instructions for formatting posts are right there next to the editing window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:property:identifier:` needs to return `NO` so that the phone does not perform it's default action. You then close the picker yourself.

```
-(BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *) peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: (ABRecordRef) person 
                                property: (ABPropertyID) property 
                              identifier: (ABMultiValueIdentifier) identifier
{
    NSLog(@"inbool"); 
    ABMultiValueRef phonePro = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property); 
    int idx = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(phonePro, identifier); 
    num.text = (NSString)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonePro, idx);                             

    [peoplePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    return NO;  
}
```

Comment: wow. i even tried that earlier and didnt test it. Thanks. It works great!